# Is it possible to use like operator in boolean column in Access

Tags: c#, .net

Is it possible to use like operator in Boolean column in Access. if so any body can point me to right link or example I will really appreciate that. I tried with text column and works fine but not with Boolean.

Thank you

for eg. If i do,

```
Select * from employee where martialStatus like 'Y%'.
```

Here, martialStatus holds Yes/No.

Comment: If it's a Boolean/bit, why would you want "like"?!

Comment: If Its boolean dude, its either true or false...yes or no...Why 'like' on it? You are going to want to pull either all Yes or all No or all, regardless of yes or no.

Comment: Makes no sense to use like, so no.

Comment: Is `martialStatus` supposed to be `maritalStatus`? Why would either of those be a boolean in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

Declare MaritalStatus as a **BIT** field

And then query it like :

> > Select * from employee where MaritalStatus = 1
> >
> > Select * from employee where MaritalStatus = 0

Answer (score 1):

`LIKE` really isn't what you want here. You want to check if column is `True`, then you should be using `WHERE boolean_column <> 0`.

This is what your Access database query should look like:

```
SELECT * FROM employee WHERE martialStatus <> 0
```

Comment: +1 for the `<> 0`. I try to suppress the memories of hunting down issues due to true being `-1`.

Comment: Yeah, it's the most reliable method. I believe that `WHERE martialStatus` will work as well. Although it's less keystrokes, the query loses a little descriptive quality (in my opinion).